# Нужно создать функцию для построения пирамиды, исходя из рандомного количества кубиков основы?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func drawCube() {
    let cube = UIView()
    cube.frame.origin.x = 40
    cube.frame.origin.y = 500
    cube.frame.size.width = 40
    cube.frame.size.height = 40
    cube.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.addSubview(cube)    
}
```

Функция с исходными параметрами кубика.
Цифровые значения не являются существенными, это просто для примера.
Если можно, то я хотел бы разобраться в основных моментах алгоритма, поэтому просьба оставить комментарий к функции.

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вам надо. например, если в основе 5 кубиков, написать цикл 5-4-3-2-1?

Comment: Например, если в основе 5 кубиков то в ряду выше 4, еще выше 3 и так далее, и кубики на ряду выше должны смещается, что б образовать как бы равномерную "елку".

Comment: Я в разработке под айос не бум бум но тут вроде элементарная логика. Рисуете циклом ваши квадраты смещая точку вправо на сторону квадрата. Когда цикл их нарисует рисовать выше с отступом на половину стороны квадрата. Тут походу цикл в цикле. Вообщем все легко.

Comment: Умел бы писать под яблоки привёл б код

Comment: Спасибо, логику то я и сам понимаю, только недавно начал изучать swift, для меня на данный момент является проблемой отобразить это в коде)

Comment: ну напишите на том языке, который знаете, я "переведу"

Comment: Это мой первый язык)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Далеко не оптимально, но как начальная точка должно пойти

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let foundation = 5

    let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x:40,y:200)
    let cubeSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        for i in stride(from: foundation, to: 0, by: -1) {
            print(i)
            for j in 0...i-1 {
                let coordX = Int(bottomLeft.x)+j*Int(cubeSize.width)+Int(cubeSize.width)/2*(foundation-i)
                let coordY = Int(bottomLeft.y)+i*Int(cubeSize.height)
                self.drawCube(coordinate: CGPoint(x: coordX, y: coordY))
            }
        }
    }

    func drawCube(coordinate:CGPoint) {
        let cube = UIView()
        cube.frame.origin.x = coordinate.x
        cube.frame.origin.y = coordinate.y
        cube.frame.size.width = self.cubeSize.width
        cube.frame.size.height = self.cubeSize.height
        cube.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        cube.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cube.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        view.addSubview(cube)
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, если не сложно могли бы вы прокомментировать работу цикла?
И что нужно изменить в коде что б foundation был рандомным?
Когда пытаюсь задать его рандомным Xcode начинает ругатся.
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: внутренний рисует один ряд кубов, внешний отвечает за ряды и сколько кубов в каждом